# DefaultErrorHandler doesn't log not retryable exceptions

Tags: spring-kafka

Not retryable exceptions are not logged in `DefaultErrorHandler` when used with `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer`.

```
@Bean
public CommonErrorHandler consumerErrorHandler(KafkaTemplate<String, KafkaMessage> kafkaTemplate) {
    var errorHandler = new DefaultErrorHandler(new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(kafkaTemplate), kafkaConsumerRetryProperties.getBackoffPolicy());
    errorHandler.addNotRetryableExceptions(NullPointerException.class);
    return errorHandler;
}
```

In this case `NullPointerException` is not logged whatsoever when thrown in method annotated with `@KafkaListener`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel free to open an issue on GitHub. In the meantime, you could subclass the DLPR and log the exception in `accept()` before calling `super.accept()`.